# Firebase Firestore how to return a onSnapshot data value from a function

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

I'm on react native making an application that when the componentDidMount.

```
componentDidMount() {
    const logs = this.getlogs();
    console.log(logs) // I'm getting undefined here
}
```

I want to get the logs when the logs method. This is my getLogs method.

```
getlogs() {
    const { user } = this.context;
    var logs = [];
    let tempObject = '';
    firebase.firestore().collection("logs").where('user', "==", 
      user).onSnapshot(querySnapshot => {
      querySnapshot.forEach(doc => {
        tempObject = doc.data();
        tempObject.id = doc.id;
        logs.push(tempObject)
      });
      return logs
});
```

Here i'm trying to return the logs. I know I'm getting the value inside the foreach loop

Comment: That `getLogs` method doesn't actually return logs.  
It returns logs from the callback passed to `onSnapshot`. Consider using redux or `useReducer` hook for something like this.